# Zero Lemma for integrals over a sphere

Tags: integration

This question may be obvious, but I'm having difficulty proving it one way or another.

I have some function $f$ on a hemisphere- it needn't be continuous necessarily but it's integrable.

Then, I have that the integral of $f$ over any spherical wedge (Lune) with its antipodal points on the edge of the great circle bounding the hemisphere is 0. Is it necessarily the case, then that $f=0$ except on a set of measure 0? Is it the case if $f=f(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the polar angle?

Answer (score 1):

The result you are asking about is essentially a special case of Peter Ungar's wonderfully-named *Freak theorem about functions on a sphere* (published in the Journal of the LMS in 1954, [J. London Math. Soc. (1954) s1-29 (1): 100-103](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-29/1.toc)): in slightly adjusted form, it goes as follows:

Let
$$ \Pi_n(\mu) = \int_{\mu}^1 P_n(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{n}(P_{n+1}(\mu)-\mu P_n(\mu)) $$
where $P_n$ are the Legendre polynomials. We have:

> **Theorem:** Let $u \in L^1(S^2)$, and suppose that
>   $$ \int_{B(p,\alpha)} u \, dV = 0 \tag{1} $$
>   for every geodesic ball $B(p,\alpha)$ of radius $\alpha$. Then if $\alpha$ is not a zero of any of the polynomials $ \Pi_n(\cos{\alpha})$, $n=1,2,3,\dotsc$, we have $u=0$ (up to a null set, of course).

Ungar also proves that if $\Pi_n (\cos{\alpha})=0$, the spherical harmonics of order $n$ satisfy (1) for any $B(p,\alpha)$. This is a fairly simple calculation involving the addition formula for spherical harmonics.

In this case, of course we have $\alpha=\pi/2$, so we are looking at $\Pi_n(0) = P_{n+1}(0)/n$, which it is easy to see is zero precisely when $n$ is positive and even (since then $P_{n+1}$ is an odd function). Therefore, (1) holds for any hemisphere for any even-order spherical harmonic.

(This result generalises to higher dimensions entirely straightforwardly using the same techniques with Gegenbauer polynomials: this is covered in Theorem 7 in the paper [*Pompeiu’s problem on spaces of constant curvature*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02786707) by Carlos A. Berenstein and Lawrence Zalcman (Journal d’Analyse Mathématique, December 1976, Volume 30, Issue 1, pp 113-130), although this is not the original discovery of such an extension: that appears to be [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X69901607) by Rolf Schneider, although his exposition has some unusual notation, among other things.)

Comment: Just to clear up your conclusion: Is the take-home message that my conjecture was false, because the even-order spherical harmonics have this property? Yet they don't have the property that they have support only in a single hemisphere, so is it fair to assume that I can't find a convex mixture of them that does?

Comment: Mm. On rereading, I see this doesn't quite answer the question, but instead reduces it to the question about whether any sum of even-order spherical harmonics gives a function which is zero on a hemisphere. It is easy to see that you can't have $f(\theta,\phi)=g(\theta)e^{im\phi}$, because $P_n^m(x)$ with $n$ even is odd/even if $m$ is odd/even, so  $g$ is then odd/even about $\theta=\pi/2$. I'm not sure about the general case: it would probably not be a bad idea to ask a separate question: the pseudo-1D cases I've just mentioned seem a lot easier to the untrained eye than the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about the upper hemisphere. Define $f = 0$ at all points except the north pole, where it's 1. This satisfies your hypotheses, but $f$ is not the zero function.

So: no.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the OP to more accurately reflect the question I was trying to ask.

Comment: Did you want to finish that last sentence, about how "$f$ has support"? Pretty much every function has SOME support!

Comment: My apologies! I've added a little more detail but the support part was spurious